# how do I remove regression line from scatterplotMatrix?

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to remove the regression lines from scatterplotMatrix. I've tried this but that does not work

```
library(car)
scatterplot.matrix(~mpg+disp+drat+wt|cyl, data=mtcars,
   main="Three Cylinder Options", reg.line=F, lwd=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of `scatterplotMatrix`, you will notice argument `smoother`. Set it to `NULL`.

```
scatterplot.matrix(~mpg+disp+drat+wt|cyl, data=mtcars,
   main="Three Cylinder Options", reg.line=F, lwd=0, smoother = NULL)
```